# How to adjust for slow sampling when animating

Tags: python, animation

I am getting input from a serial interface, and I am using it to move up to three digital needles.  I have three gauges, and I can sample at a rate of around 10 Hz regularly, shared between all the gauges.  When I'm only running one gauge, the needle moves very smoothly with a 10Hz input, but as soon as I add another one, the needle gets rather jumpy.

I need to figure out a way to smooth out the data so my needle doesn't jump so much when the sample rate slows down.

I am using the following code to change the angle of the needle in a more realistic manner:

```
def move(self):
    self.real_angle = self.real_angle + ((360 - self.value * 270/120) - self.real_angle) * 0.2
    needle_angle = self.real_angle
    if needle_angle > 360:
        needle_angle = 360
    self.needle.angle = needle_angle
```

self.real_angle is the angle the needle is actually at (it may be above 360 degrees).  self.value is the value returned from the serial port.  self.needle_angle isn't really important here.  I simply use that to set my angle, because the real angle may be higher than 360 degrees.

This code gives a more realistic analogue style motion, and looks great at high sample rates, but I'm trying to figure out how to make the needle move more smoothly.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you set the target angle desired, and them smoothly `-=` or `+=` your way there at fixed millisecond intervals? You can even adjust the velocity given the delta between currently displayed position and target position

Comment: I'm not sure how to adjust the velocity is the problem.  When the needle is at 30 degrees at frame 0, and the needle is at 40 degrees at frame 8, and the needle hasn't gotten to 30 degrees yet, the velocity suddenly increases by the difference between where the needle is compared to 30 and 40, so at least 10.

If I could somehow take a couple samples and make an assumption that the speed would increase at the same rate, it might help, but I'm not exactly sure how to code that.